# Open Source Software that combines Snort and Cisco Blocked Lists

Tags: linux, networking, security

There used to be this software that existed maybe 8-10 years ago (I thought it was maybe called FloodGate?) It worked by having a Linux box bridge running snort or prelude.  When it detected a DOS or DDOS attack (and presumably others), it would actually connect to your Cisco routers and block the source IP at the router.

Has anyone heard of this software or know where I can get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you talking snortsam http://www.snortsam.net/

Comment: I'm pretty sure I was following a different open source project (or maybe it got renamed), but this looks pretty good.  Thank You!